# Generic domain creation - domain.myGenericDomain

Tags: tld

Is it theoretically possible to register a new top-level domain (so I would have a page like page.mydomain)? If yes, then where is it possible and how much is it?

Comment: Think you want subdomains. Most web host let you create this. www.godaddy.com is an example

Comment: No, I mean generic domains like .com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [TLDs (Top-Level Domains)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). Historically, only countries and large interest groups could register TLDs, but recently ICANN, the organisation in charge internet domain names, opened bidding for corporate TLDs. You can see a current list of applications [here](https://gtldresult.icann.org/application-result/applicationstatus/viewstatus). To apply for one yourself, I believe the entering price is somewhere around $10,000, but I'm not sure. Either way, the wait for authorisation is probably still over a year, so I wouldn't count on getting it done soon or cheap.